# How can I find the Taylor series for $e^{\sqrt(x)}$ with center $c=1$?

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion

How can I find the Taylor series representation for $e^{\sqrt(x)}$ with center $c=1$? I don't think it is mathematically legal to simply take the square root of $x$ in the power series for $e^{x}$, but correct me if I'm wrong.

Should I go through and take derivatives? I am a little confused how to go about this.

Comment: This reason isn't a very good one because $(\sqrt{x})^2$ does have a Taylor series at $0$ even though $\sqrt{x}$ does not. The problem is that the composition is not differentiable at $0$.

Comment: Fine, $|x|$ does not have a Taylor series at $0$ but $(|x|)^2$ does. My point is that  there are examples where $f(g(x))$ has a Taylor series even when $g(x)$ does not, and your first comment implies that this is impossible.

Comment: >  I don't think it is mathematically legal to simply take the square root of $x$ in the power series for $e^x$. Why do you think that? I'm also very curious to know the reason.

Comment: Assuming that you mean the Taylor series expansion about $x=0$ this is not possible because the first derivative of $e^{\sqrt{x}}$ at $x=0$ is undefined. Otherwise we can just use the normal technique by evaluating the $n$th derivatives of this function at the point $x=x_0$.

Comment: @fishfag because I'm pretty sure you can only perform linear operations on series (and square root is not one of those).

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series+exp%28sqrt%28x%29%29

Comment: You can substitute whatever function of $x$ you want in $e^x$ and get some sort of infinite sum, but it won't be a Taylor series.

Comment: @Math1000 how would I get to that answer (i.e., writing it out)?

Comment: Simply replace $x^k$ with $x^{k/2}$ in the series, but as in the deleted answer, it is actually a Puiseux series because it is no longer a series in $x^k$ but rather in $x^{k/2}$. There is no "Taylor series" for this function because, as @PeterForeman pointed out, we cannot evaluate derivatives of $e^{\sqrt x}$ at zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expand by differentiation.

$f(x) = e^{\sqrt(x)}, f'(x)=e^{\sqrt(x)}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}, ...$
to produce:

$e^{\sqrt(x)} + e^{\sqrt(x)}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}(x-1) + ...$